# Setting additional options for configurable product in Quote Item [Solved]

Tags: product, cart, configurable-product, quote

I am trying to add the option 'additional_options' to a quote item representing a configurable after I add it to the cart.

```
$newItem = $quoteItem->getQuote()->addProduct($product,$productOptions);
$newItem->addOption('code'=> 'additional_options', 'product_id'=> $product->getId(), 'value'=> $value);
$newItem->addOption(array('code' => 'my_custom_data', 'value' => serialize($myCustomData)));
$newItem->setCustomPrice(0)->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
```

This is working perfectly with a simple product but on a configurable none of the additional_options show up in the cart and the price remains unmodified.

I checked the sales_flat_quote_item_options and the new configurable product does not have the additional_options entry, but the simple products do. The my_custom_data option is saved and usable in the cart just not the additional_options.

It seems like the quote is purposefully ignoring the changes to the configurable product. I have attempted to set this information on both the parent item and the child item, but getting the child item before the quote is saved seems to be unreliable since the $newItem->getChildren() always returns an empty and there are no Id's set yet.

Is there another way to set this information for configurable products or is this just some more of Magento's magical repeated code that was overlooked during an update?

----- Edit - Solved --------

I solved the problem with the following:

$newItem = $quoteItem->getQuote()->addProduct($product,$productOptions)**->getParentItem()**;

Looks like adding a configurable product to the quote actually returns the child and not the visual product. This seems a little bit unexpected since you supply the options for the parent product but get the derived product in return. Although this does fix all of my issues.

Comment: Here is some answers, maybe it helpfull: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9156/need-to-add-a-custom-order-attribute/9259

Comment: That code has the same problem, it works on simple products but the option "additional_options" added to the quote item does not get saved when applied to a configurable product.

Comment: What is your purpose using quote item option, maybe we will offer another solution if you give your final purpose.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept your answer.